# Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$, a commutative ring with identity. Show that $(I,a) = \{i+ra: i\in I, r\in R\}$ for fixed $a\in R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$, a commutative ring with identity. Fix an element $a\in R$. The ideal generated by the set $I\cup \{a\}$ is denoted $(I,a)$. Assuming that $a\notin I$, prove that $$(I,a)=\{i+ra: i\in I, r\in R\}.$$

Attempted proof:

By definition, the ideal generated by a subset $S\subseteq R$ is all linear combinations of elements in $S$ together with elements of $R$. Therefore, the ideal generated by $I\cup \{a\}$ will look like

$$(I,a) = \{r_1 i_1 + r_2i_2+\cdots+r_ka +\cdots+r_ni_n : r_\alpha \in R; i_\alpha \in I; n\in \mathbb N\}.$$

However since $I$ is an ideal and closed under multiplication by elements in $R$, each $r_\alpha i_\alpha = j$ for some $j \in I$. Moreover, since $I$ is closed under addition then $\sum j_\alpha = k$ for some $k \in I$. Therefore, all elements of $(I,a)$ take the form of $i + ra$ for some $i\in I$ and $r\in R$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks basically correct to me (though I haven't read it in complete detail).  Another approach would be to show double inclusion, and for one of the directions, it would be useful to apply the lemma: Suppose $I$ is an ideal and $S \subseteq I$.  Then $\langle S \rangle \subseteq I$ where $\langle S \rangle$ is the ideal generated by the set $S$.

Comment: Hint: $\ J\supseteq I,a\iff J\supseteq I,aR\iff J\supseteq I+aR \ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this definition of generated ideal, i'd say your proof is correct apart from some minor notation inconsistency (what are the $j_{\alpha}$? I assume they are the $r_{\alpha}i_{\alpha}$ ?) You showed that $(I,a) \subset \{i+ra: i\in I, r\in R\}.$ By definition each element $i+ra$ is a linear combination of elements in $I\cup \{a\}$, so the other inclusion $\{i+ra: i\in I, r\in R\} \subset (I,a)$ holds as well, this is trivial and may not need to be mentioned, but to be 100% sure you could add it.

Note: I know the Ideal generated by a subset to be defined as smallest ideal that contains the subset. So an alternative proof would be to show that $\{i+ra: i\in I, r\in R\}$ is an ideal by just verifying the axioms and then showing that every ideal that contains $I \cup a$ must contain all elements of the form $\{i+ra: i\in I, r\in R\}$.